# node webkit - Support for mnemonics in menus

Tags: node-webkit, nw.js

Is there any way to create Menus with submenus and parent menu having mnemonics?
For example 
Parent Menu = Options (Alt+o)
Submenus - Save (Ctrl+s), Open (Ctrl+o), Exit (Ctrl+x)

On hitting Alt+o - submenu should show up

Comment: start here: http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/MenuItem/

Comment: Followed the docs, able to create submenus with shortcut key, but shortcut key of parent is not showing up its submenu

Comment: Could you give us an example, please?

Comment: var optionsMenu = new gui.MenuItem({
                label: 'Options',
                key: 'o',
                modifiers: 'alt'
            });
            var optionsSubmenu = new gui.Menu();
            optionsSubmenu.append(new gui.MenuItem({ label: 'Open...', key: 'l', modifiers: 'ctrl', click: function() { console.log('clicked!'); } }));
            optionsMenu.submenu = optionsSubmenu;
            menu.append(optionsMenu);
            gui.Window.get().menu = menu;